# How to retrieve data on server side with node.js sent by frontend ajax via post method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I recently started learning node.js with express framework and stumbled upon a problem.

I'm trying out a simple query search webapp and I want to pass a piece of data(a boolean called all)

from front-end plain javascript via ajax to the server side, but the current code

that I have written as of right now, it seems that my data was not passed to the server side,

the 3 console.log that I planted all return {}.

What concept am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?

If any additional info is needed, pls let me know, Thanks.

**front end js**

```
window.onload=function(){
console.log("window loaded");
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST","http://127.0.0.1:3000/search", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status==200){
        // code later to be implemented
    }
}
let searchConditions = new SearchConditions(true);
console.log('data='+JSON.stringify(searchConditions));
xhr.send('data='+JSON.stringify(searchConditions));
}

class SearchConditions{
    constructor(all) {
        this.all = all;
    }
}
```

**backend node.js**

```
// only partial code

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/search', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.query);
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

**my browser log**

[image]

**my backendlog**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you send invalid data:

```js
xhr.send('data='+JSON.stringify(searchConditions));
```

JSON Objects do not have variable declarations. What your Server gets is:

```
'data = {"all": true }'
```

This is not even a valid variable declaration.
What your server should get is:

```
{"all": true}
```

Try to send the plain JSON Object without a variable declaration and set the "Content-Type"-header to json:

```js
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(searchConditions));
```

Comment: Hi! I made it work by adding setRequestHeader and removing the 'data=' in the send method, however, I still had to keep the JSON.stringify(searchConditions) and not just searchConditions like you mentioned, if you could elaborate on that and edited your answer, I would gladly accept this as the solution, thanks.

Comment: Oh, okay. Haven't worked with plain XHR requests in a while. I corrected it, my bad!